# Launching task from one method and cancel it from another one

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

I'm starting to use the Task mechanism and I can't figure out how to 
make

- A method to start the job
- Another one to cancel this one.

Doing the creation and the cancel from the same method works (like with the commented code in StartTask).

But when i use my CancelTask method, it don't works ! (job continue to turn and taskProgress continue to be incremented).

My framework version is .NET 4 and project is ASP.NET MVC 3

Thank's by advance !

```
private static int taskProgress = 0;
public CancellationTokenSource ts = new CancellationTokenSource();

public ActionResult StartTask()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (ts.IsCancellationRequested)
                break;

            Thread.Sleep(100);
            taskProgress++;
        }
    }, ts.Token);

    //Thread.Sleep(3000);
    //ts.Cancel();

    return RedirectToAction("GetTaskProgress");
}

public ActionResult CancelTask()
{
    ts.Cancel();
    return Content("Cancelled (percentage="+taskProgress.ToString()+")");
}

public ActionResult GetTaskProgress()
{
    return Content(taskProgress.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution.
The CancellationTokenSource need to be static.

```
public static CancellationTokenSource ts = new CancellationTokenSource();
```

Comment: Do you really want this member to be static?  Remember that static members aren't bound to an instance of a class.  You will have problems if you need multiple objects of the above class.

Comment: Apparently, it's mandatory to make it works.
I think the reason is that i use 2 actions methods who can be called from separate "contexts" and then using a static property make this one unique from all the "contexts".

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by separate "contexts", but if you want the cancellation token to be shared across instances, then yes, static is what you need.

Comment: The CancellationTokenSource doesn't have to be static at all. Actually this is the first time I've seen a static tcs.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos So how you would make that ? I'm curious of another ways :)